# IE will not open my website instead trying to download it

Tags: django, apache, internet-explorer, ubuntu

Chrome, Safari, and Firefox all display my website normally. Yet, it seems that IE does not see my website as an HTML file and instead asks to download it when I input the URL. When I select open it downloads the file and asks which program to open it as. When I select IE it displays like a normal webpage.

If there is any code that would help answer this question I am happy to share, but I am not sure where to even begin.

I am on a AWS/Ubuntu/Django stack.

Comment: So I located the source of the problem. If I remove the context_dict in views.py, the site loads on IE like a normal webpage. But when I try to pass a context_dict, IE tries to download it as an unkown file type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by switching from render_to_response to render.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the Content-Type Response header it would be `{}`, To fix that I've created the middleware and it works

```
class ContentTypeMiddleware(object):

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        response['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'

    return response
```